# What is the problem while updating: "W: Failed to fetch ... No Hash entry in Release file ..."

Tags: upgrade, updates

This is the output of the command # apt-get update. I cannot update any packages with update manager either. What is the problem?

```
Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb InRelease                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease                                 
Get:1 http://www.remastersys.com precise InRelease [2,069 B]                   
Get:2 http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb Release.gpg [836 B]             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease               
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                       
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb Release                           
Hit http://www.remastersys.com precise/main i386 Packages                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                      
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]                    
Hit http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/apps i386 Packages                
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]            
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B]          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Ign http://www.remastersys.com precise/main TranslationIndex                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/games i386 Packages               
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]           
Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/apps TranslationIndex             
Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/games TranslationIndex            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                          
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]           
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [934 kB]                 
Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US            
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B]          
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources [5,019 kB]           
Ign http://www.remastersys.com precise/main Translation-en_US                  
Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/apps Translation-en               
Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/apps Translation-bn               
Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/games Translation-en_US           
Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/games Translation-en              
Ign http://www.remastersys.com precise/main Translation-en                     
Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org precise-getdeb/games Translation-bn              
Ign http://www.remastersys.com precise/main Translation-bn                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-bn                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-bn                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-bn                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-bn                       
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources [155 kB]           
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [1,274 kB]         
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [1,274 kB]         
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages [8,431 B]    
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [4,796 kB]     
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages [121 kB]     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [46.9 kB]        
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [1,379 B]  
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [14.4 kB]    
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [696 B]    
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [120 kB]   
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [2,439 B]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [37.1 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [1,393 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex        
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources [700 B]        
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]   
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources [4,404 B]  
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources [14 B]   
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages [559 B]  
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages [3,167 B]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex    
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [12.6 kB]       
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [14 B]    
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [4,522 B]   
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [696 B]   
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [43.9 kB] 
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [10.3 kB]
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,393 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-bn                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en         
Fetched 12.8 MB in 11min 35s (18.4 kB/s)                                       
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_i18n_Index

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

open your terminal and do this

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_universe_i18n_Index

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Would you tell me why this error occurred?

Comment: the Hash mismatch , so to fix it we have deleted and regenerated with sudo apt-get update.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

still fail for me :(

Comment: Ok go to update manager and choose best server