# Sudo apt-get update problem 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates, software-sources

Please Guys help me to fix this issues with update my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop:

```
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en [3,341 kB]
Fetched 24.5 MB in 7min 9s (57.1 kB/s)                                         
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Index  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Can you provide us the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file? (repost for correction on the file name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the problem while updating: "W: Failed to fetch ... No Hash entry in Release file ..."](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143494/what-is-the-problem-while-updating-w-failed-to-fetch-no-hash-entry-in-rel)

Answer (score 1):

**First**,

make sure your internet connection is good and stable, try to stick with a trusted server (if you recently changed apt-get server change back to one of the main servers).

**Then**,

move the file prompting the error:

```
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/
sudo mv extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index main_copy
```

update gpg key:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 40976EAF437D05B5
```

rebuild cache:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
```

**Finally**,

update, clean, autoclean, and autoremove for good measure before attempting to upgrade again:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You could replace `sudo apt-get upgrade` with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` if that is what you were originally aiming for in the first place.

If you encounter any errors, please post them.

sources:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82707/failing-on-apt-get-update

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983355

and

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1967783.html

Comment: You may need to open up your firewall to update the key if your security settings are strict.

Comment: Hi man and thank you for your answer, i have tried your solution but there no change.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have entered `sudo mv extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Index main_copy`

Comment: try it now, my bad

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82707/failing-on-apt-get-update